# How to redirect standard error to a file

Tags: linux, bash, io-redirection

In linux if I want to redirect standard error to a file, I can do this:

```
$ls -l /bin/usr 2> ls-error.txt
```

But when I try:

```
$foo=
$echo ${foo:?"parameter is empty"} 2> ls-error.txt
```

The result in terminal is:

```
bash: foo: parameter is empty
```

It doesn't work!
Can somebody explain why?
I thought `${parameter:?word}` would send the value of word to standard error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo ${foo:?"parameter is empty"}  2>ls-error.txt` redirects the `stderr` of `echo`, but the error message is produced by the shell while expanding
`${foo:?"parameter is empty"}`.

You can get the result you want by redirecting a block (or a subshell) instead so that the shell's stderr is included in the redirection:

```
{ echo "${foo:?"parameter is empty"}"; } 2>ls-error.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:
     ($echo ${foo:?"parameter is empty"}) 2> ls-error.txt

Answer (score -1):

In case you would like to redirect both sandard and error output, AND to still get these messages when executing your command, you can use the **tee** command:

```
$echo ${foo:?"parameter is empty"} |& tee -a ls-error.txt
```